# NSPredicate in NSFetchedResultsController acting strange

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, nspredicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"List.name == 'kristof\\'s list'"];
```

Works as expected.
However I want do something like this:

```
    NSString *listName = [[[detailItem valueForKey:@"name"] description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"List.name == '%@'", listName];
```

It returns nothing, even if I try this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"List.name == '%@'", @"kristof\\'s list"];
```

It remains empty. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of [NSString stringWithFormat] and [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat] are different. NSString performs the substitution on creation, whereas NSPredicate on evaluation. Your single quotes are preventing the substitution.

For more take a look at the [CocoaDev Forums](http://cocoadev.com/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=308).